# Testing S3 permissions for security

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have to test S3 read / write permissions by fully logging out of S3. I use a aws sso login command to login everyday. I tried:

```
aws s3 ls s3://[S3 bucket name]
```

and I get: Error loading SSO Token: Token for https://a-000.awsapps.com/start does not exist

It still tried to connect via SSO token. How do I ensure I can test the S3 being fully logged out?

Other s3 commands also get me this message in return:

The SSO session associated with this profile has expired or is otherwise invalid. To refresh this SSO session run aws sso login with the corresponding profile.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Docker. It's really simple and you can be sure that there are no credentials whatsoever because it's an isolated environment:

```
docker run -it --rm amazon/aws-cli s3 ls s3://mybucket
```

Outputs: *Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".*

This is 'fully logged out'. However, `aws` CLI requires *some* credentials to work. I suggest that you create a new SSO role or IAM user, maybe even in a different account, and use the new credentials to authenticate `aws` CLI and test your S3 buckets. You may still want to use Docker for it. Consider this command:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint="" amazon/aws-cli bash
```

This will spin up a fresh container with `aws` CLI and give you access to the shell. From there you can set `aws` credentials and run your `aws s3` commands.

Comment: yes I tried aws sso logout, that is how it logged me out in the first place. This docker command might work beautifully, what is --rm amazon/aws-cli for , since its an isolated environment?

Comment: @mugi `--rm` means 'automatically clean up the container and remove the file system when the container exits'; `amazon/aws-cli` is the official AWS CLI Docker image on DockerHub.

Comment: the output I get with this docker command is "Unable to locate credentials, You can configure credentials by running "aws configure" '  - when I try it on personal system.

Comment: @mugi you wrote 'fully logging out of S3' - isn't this what you wanted? The error message suggest you are not authenticated in any way.

Comment: Yes, so I cannot get an output back to determine if my S3 is allowing me to red / write / ls etc to determine if my policy allows outside access? how do I know its trying to reach my s3 bucket and how do I check if its successful ?

Comment: @mugi how do you want to simulate outside access? Do you have a different SSO role or a pair of aws keys, or...?

Comment: its sort of like- 

you have certain s3 buckets that you have been told are in need of tightening, so in order to test if they allow READ/WRITE I need to try and upload a dummy file to them after fully logging out from AWS SSO etc. 

- which I did, but how do I know if it actually was able to connect with my bucket or no if the only output I get is "AWS not configuired"